# creating sum of the values in nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary looks like the below:

```py
my_single_dictionary={
    "totals": {"total": 26, "correct": 12, "false": 14, "correct_Percent": 46.15384615384615, "wrong_percent": 53.84615384615385},
    "label": {"ADDRESS": {"total": 11, "correct": 2, "false": 9, "correct_Percent": 18.181818181818183, "wrong_percent": 81.81818181818183}, 
              "NAME": {"total": 9, "correct": 6, "false": 3, "correct_Percent": 66.66666666666666, "wrong_percent": 33.33333333333333}, 
              "DATE_TIME": {"total": 6, "correct": 4, "false": 2, "correct_Percent": 66.66666666666666, "wrong_percent": 33.33333333333333}}
}
```

##### Here is pseudo-code?

```py
grand_sum_percentages={}
for new_dictiony in list_of_10_dictionaies:
    similar_to_my_single_dictiony
# updating the percentage_correct and percentage_wrong based on the sum of wrong and correct of two dictionaries 
    for values in similar_to_my_single_dictiony.values():
        values+my_single_dictionary.values()
    some way to calculate the grand sum of `total`,               `correct`,`false`
```

#### What do I want to do?

I have a list of dictionaries, a single dictionary looks like `my_single_dictionary`
I have percentage correct and percentage wrong for total and label `{name, email, phone}` wise.
Now in the loop, I want to get a grand sum of percentage for all the dictionaries not a single one.

#### My final dictionary should look like this:

```
{'totals': {'total': 2000,
  'correct': 200,
  'false': 1800,
  'correct_Percent': xx.xx,
  'wrong_percent': xx.xx},
 'label': {'ADDRESS': {'total': 300,
   'correct': 150,
   'false': 150,
   'correct_Percent': xx,
   'wrong_percent': xx},
  'NAME': {'total': 600,
   'correct': 200,
   'false': 400,
   'correct_Percent': xxx,
   'wrong_percent': xxx}}}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from translating your pseudo-code into real code?

Comment: Where is your list of dictionaries?

Comment: from where do you get a total of 2000 in your final dictionary?

Comment: It sum up form all single dictonaries what I loop over. I have list of many  and look like same what is in `my_single_dict`: just want to sum the values of the all dictionories

Comment: @MadPhysicist just assuming any list that is collection of dictionary and and key valuse are similar to `my_single_dictionary`

Comment: Please use precise terminology and avoid assumptions. The help you get will be proportional to the accuracy of your description.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can iterate over the keys to sum the values within. This works for the `"totals"` key, you should figure out how to do the `"label"` yourself.

```
dictionary_list = [{
    "totals": {"total": 26, "correct": 12, "false": 14, "correct_Percent": 46.15384615384615, "wrong_percent": 53.84615384615385},
    "label": {"ADDRESS": {"total": 11, "correct": 2, "false": 9, "correct_Percent": 18.181818181818183, "wrong_percent": 81.81818181818183}, 
              "NAME": {"total": 9, "correct": 6, "false": 3, "correct_Percent": 66.66666666666666, "wrong_percent": 33.33333333333333}, 
              "DATE_TIME": {"total": 6, "correct": 4, "false": 2, "correct_Percent": 66.66666666666666, "wrong_percent": 33.33333333333333}}
}]

for i in range(9):
    dictionary_list.append(dictionary_list[0].copy())

# Relevant part of the code for you below this line 
final_dict = {"totals" : {}, "label" : {"ADDRESS": {}, "NAME": {}, "DATE_TIME": {}}}

for key in dictionary_list[0]["totals"]:
    for dictionary in dictionary_list:
        if key not in final_dict["totals"]:
            final_dict["totals"][key] = 0
        final_dict["totals"][key] += dictionary["totals"][key]

print(final_dict)
```